# PHP pdo get all values for a key in result set

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I am trying to find a way to get all the data that is returned from my mysql query to be fetched as per the key, such that I get all the values for that specific key, For example if this is the array of results I get from my pdo fetchAll() method ,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => user1
            [country] => USA
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => user2
            [country] => Canada
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => user3
            [country] => Iceland
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => user4
            [country] => Scotland
        )

)
```

what is the best way to fetch all the countries from this result array? I am not so good with looping over multi-dimensional arrays. sorry if this is a very silly question I'm still a beginner in PHP.

Comment: [fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_KEY_PAIR)](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#pairs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP provides a handy function called `array_column()` for this purpose, you can pass the key as an parameter to this function call and it will return an array of columns' data,

**Please make sure you're using PHP 5.5 or greater for this to work**

```
$result_set = YOUR_RESULT_ARRAY_HERE;
print_r(array_column($result_set, 'country'));

//output
Array
(
    [0] => USA
    [1] => Canada
    [2] => Scotland
    [3] => Iceland
)
```